# BeautifulSoup can't parse YouTube pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do some simple web page scraping using Python's BeautifulSoup library, and I run into a UnicodeDecodeError when a try to parse most YouTube pages.

It seems YouTube is serving up HTMl with invalid characters in it. That's a problem on their end, of course, but I thought the whole point of BeautifulSoup was that it could handle incorrect pages and make a best-effort guess at the results. I would be happy if it just discarded the invalid characters. I'm far from a Unicode expert, and the various magical incantations I have tried of `encode` and `decode` have not done me any good.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to deal with this error. I would prefer not to make my code YouTube specific, as it needs to handle lots of user-specified web pages.

Here's a very simple code snippet that demonstrates the problem:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9MzrirPrCI'
text = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
```

The final line results in the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/cygdrive/d/home/ll-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

/cygdrive/d/home/ll-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, **kwargs)
    170
    171         try:
--> 172             self._feed()
    173         except StopParsing:
    174             pass

/cygdrive/d/home/ll-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.pyc in _feed(self)
    183         self.builder.reset()
    184
--> 185         self.builder.feed(self.markup)
    186         # Close out any unfinished strings and close all the open tags.
    187         self.endData()

/cygdrive/d/home/ll-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.pyc in feed(self, markup)
    193     def feed(self, markup):
    194         self.parser.feed(markup)
--> 195         self.parser.close()
    196
    197     def test_fragment_to_document(self, fragment):

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.1.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.17-i686.egg/lxml/etree.dll in lxml.etree._FeedParser.close (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:88786)()

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.1.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.17-i686.egg/lxml/etree.dll in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98085)()

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.1.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.17-i686.egg/lxml/etree.dll in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97909)()

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.1.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.17-i686.egg/lxml/etree.dll in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:9071)()

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.1.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.17-i686.egg/lxml/etree.dll in lxml.etree._handleSaxData (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94081)()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 22: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: try use scrapy instead.

Comment: I am using version 4.1.3 and it works fine

Comment: If I go back to version 3 of BeautifulSoup it works. 4.1.3 still doesn't gives the above error. Moj, did you try it on the same URL as I did?

Comment: Nobody has any clue how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

There are encoding issue with BeautifulSoup 4 up to version 4.0.3 and its a bug which has been fixed in latest version.So you should upgrade your beautiful soup to latest.

You can upgrade beautiful soup to latest version using pip  (if you are using pip)

```
pip install beautifulsoup --upgrade
```

While writing this answer beautiful soup is 4.3.2 which contains no problem regarding encoding.

Also i tried your code on latest bs4 and there are no such issues.

Answer (score 0):

try `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")` before importing beautifulsoup module?

Comment: @EddieSullivan，make sure your file use utf-8 encoding. add `#encoding: utf-8` in the beginning of your module. (after `#!/usr/bin/python`)